# Display a warning for non standard browsers

Tags: java, browser, warnings, standards

I'm building a website, it displays perfect on standard browsers i.e Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE8..

Is there a way to display a message if other than these browsers are used?

And also, if possible, display a message if non standard browser is used on a mobile phone as most of the standard browsers are hybrid..(Android)

I found lots of tutorial to do so if ie version less than 7, but none for non standard browsers, if someone could point me to a tutorial for non standard browser that would do to..

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried to achieve it?

Comment: Yes it is possible and you can give a warning to the user about upgrading the browser but i still suggests to make you website more cross browser compatible.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm not good in java, but i saw some scripts to do same if ie version less than 7..but unable to do it for rest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex Kreutznaer above explained you can use the user agent information. Just to provide a base code for you. Here is how you can do it.

Note, this information is not reliable. Browser can and do lie about who they are and what OS they run on because user agent information can be changed but for most of your users, it does the job. In term of displaying a warning you can send the value from your servlet once you detected it and show a message on the page.

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

you would need then group of if statement to identify the browsers you want or don't want in order to display or hide your warning.

here is a [link](http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/07/detecting-which-browser-in-java-servlet-filter/) with code you could use to identify the browser.

Comment: So if i do something like `String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent"); if(lt IE 8) { alert("not supported") }` i don't know java well..

Comment: I added a link for you which has all the if the text for different browsers which you can use against the userAgent String information. it also has more code for you to look at. Good luck and remember google is always your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify HTTP client via header named `User-Agent`. Use servlet or HTTP filter that verifies this header and redirects response to error page if needed.

Comment: Please don't ever do this.  Anyone can customize their user-agent string, making it essentially meaningless.  My own user-agent is something like "My favorite browser" right now!

Comment: @Brian if the client/browser misinforms the server, then it;s the client/browser problem. You cannot send non standard garbage to the server. If you you (= your browser) do it, then YOU are in trouble, not the server side.

Comment: @Brian browser is a client that wants to receive some service. In order to receive it, the browser should send correct information about its own "identity". So, checking User-Agent is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If there is absolutely no way to show a warning as a pop up, you can always do it by forwarding users to a web page, that shows the warning message.

It looks sort of awkward, but if there is no other choice, it should work.

All browsers are supposed to support at least basic HTML tags.

Comment: Yes, but for e.g i have an Android, if i see my site through chrome, looks good but my standard browser cuts of footer..it's a hybrid of Firefox and safari..